# [FirebaseAnalytics][I-ACS023001] Deep Link does not contain valid required params issue

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-dynamic-links

```
[FirebaseAnalytics][I-ACS023001] Deep Link does not contain valid required params. URL params: {
    "_cpb" = 1;
    "_cpt" = cpit;
    "_fpb" = "CIAHEJ4DGgVlbi1JTg==";
    "_iumchkactval" = 1;
    "_iumenbl" = 1;
    "_osl" = "https://helpwise.page.link/TJBU";
    "_plt" = 3322;
    "_uit" = 1679;
    apn = "com.saaslabs.helpwise";
    cid = 3913316441535437959;
    ibi = "com.saaslabs.helpwise";
    isi = 1503985272;
    link = "https://app.helpwise.io";
}
VERBOSE: application/scene didBecomeActive
DEBUG: Application Foregrounded started
DEBUG: cancelFocusCall of {
    "NOT_ATTRIBUTED" = "<OSUnattributedFocusTimeProcessor: 0x28181f8e0>";
}
```

I am getting this error how to solve it

I tried the normal integration method from the firebase website but not able to solve this issue

Answer (score 1):

This error happens if your link structure is not properly configured. You have to make sure that your [link parameter](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/create-manually) is [URL encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).

Answer (score 1):

After trying lots of methods I was final able to solve the issue.
The mistake that I made was in the app delegate I had overridden the function which intercepts those links in iOS due to which it was not able to get some information that was required commenting that line solved the issue.

those lines were:

```
 override func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
         print("app delegate=====\(userActivity.webpageURL?.absoluteString ?? "NO WEBPAGE URL")")
         return true }
```